# Tabu & multirow & lots of text in one cell problem

Tags: tables, tabu

I am in the process of creating a table that will have lots of text, however, the text seems to be escaping the boundaries of the table/cell.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\tabulinesep=1.2mm\begin{tabu}to \columnwidth{@{}X[0.5,l]X[2,l]X[2,l]X[4,l]@{}}

\toprule

Code & Factor                    & Example & Hypothesis      \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
\midrule
P    & Preposed demonstrative    &  Tiptree sits on my book while I read it.       & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabu}[l]{@{}X@{}}Cats read with their butts (Robinson 2017) Cats think books are comfy places to sleep (Robinson MC) Cats are lazy jerks who never clean up after themselves (Phyle 2000). Cats are villainous creatures bent on taking over the world and enslave human kind (Smith-Jones 1985). Cats secretly really just want to have their bellies rubbed (Leacock 1965). Polydactyl cats are the next stage in evolution where cats are striving for human dominance \end{tabu}} \\ 

D    & Postposed demonstrative   &         &    \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
S    & Simultaneous demonstratives  &         & \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
B    & Bare demonstrative        &         &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
\\ \bottomrule

\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

looks like this:

[image]

I am too tired to see the solution. I apologize, I am sure I am missing some pertinent information

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I think cats read with their moustaches;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`multirow` cell is higher than sum of heights of spanned rows. in this particular case this heights difference can be compensated with adding `\tabulinesep`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabu, tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\tabulinesep =_0.8\baselineskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {@{} l X[0.8,L] X[1,L] X[2.2,L] @{}}
    \toprule
Code & Factor                    & Example & Hypothesis         \\
    \midrule
P    & Preposed demonstrative    &  Tiptree sits on my book while I read it.       & \multirow[t]{11}{=}{Cats read with their butts (Robinson 2017) Cats think books are comfy places to sleep (Robinson MC) Cats are lazy jerks who never clean up after themselves (Phyle 2000). Cats are villainous creatures bent on taking over the world and enslave human kind (Smith-Jones 1985). Cats secretly really just want to have their bellies rubbed (Leacock 1965). Polydactyl cats are the next stage in evolution where cats are striving for human dominance}          \\
D    & Postposed demonstrative      &         &                 \\
S    & Simultaneous demonstratives  &         &                 \\
B    & Bare demonstrative           &         &                 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
```